# Android call sync. function on each app start

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Good morning together,

I have an android app, which saves data into `SQLite` database.
The app gets this data of my `MYSQL` Database via `http` post.

I would like to realize, that on each app start (if the activity with the list view will appear) the `http` post function will be execute.

Where I have to put this code?
In my `iOS` app, I can put this into the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: how your app start scope ? i mean going background and coming foreground, or user killed app recent apps den started, or os killed and restarted agian.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this in `onCreate()` .

Comment: onCreate() will be called every time the Activity gets recreated, not only on app start

Comment: for this you can make an activity named as StartUpActivity that will be called when application will start. You can show a splash on this activity and in background you can do all your stuffs. After doing all the things you want to do in background you can move to your next Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Show a progress bar each time until response processed and ListView updated with that data.

You can do it in onCreate() method by calling a method for populating data.
Ofcourse do it in background thread. Use okHTTP library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create application class and register in manifiest file

Application.onCreate() call once when application start/restart but not call when activity restart

```
import android.app.Application;



    public class MyApplication extends Application {

        //it's call when application start ;
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
         // do your work here
        }

    }
```

**AndroidManifiest.xml**

```
 <application
        android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication"
.
.
.
   >

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a Custom `Application` class to do that stuff. Because, when Activity is started and application is not loaded, then `onCreate()` methods will be called.

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        callHttpPost();
    }

    private void callHttpPost(){
         // Do Your Stuff
    }

}
```

Also set the application name in your manifest file .

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".CustomApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

       <!-- All your Activity goes here -->

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There some third party libraries if your requirement very strict.

or else you have to extend Application to create your own Application class, and make calls  in below method in your application class

```
public void onCreate ()
```

> Docs : Called when the application is starting, before any activity,
>   service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been
>   created. Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example
>   using lazy initialization of state) since the time spent in this
>   function directly impacts the performance of starting the first
>   activity, service, or receiver in a process. If you override this
>   method, be sure to call super.onCreate().